# Performance of elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman vs NIST-PQC finalist KEMS

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, embedded

I am looking for performance measurements in cycle counts for an implementation of the elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman for curve, `ed25519`. Ideally, the cycle counts should be for the M4, so that they are comparable with the `pqm4` benchmarks: https://github.com/mupq/pqm4. Are there any measurements that can be compared to this end?

In general, I would be interested in how much "slower/faster" in terms of CPU cycles a elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman performs vs. say Kyber.

Comment: [eBATS](https://bench.cr.yp.to/results-dh.html) (ECRYPT Benchmarking of Asymmetric Systems) has cycle counts for various asymmetric algorithms on various processors, though it doesn't have any Cortex M4 devices AFAIK.